# Natural deduction via completeness theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I have some question about how to use completeness theorem, I need to show the follow:

Let $\Sigma$ be a consistent set of propositions and $\phi, \psi$ formulas. Show that

1. If $\Sigma\not\vdash \phi$ then $\Sigma\vdash\neg \phi$
2. If $\Sigma\not\vdash \phi$ then $\Sigma\not\vdash[\phi\lor (\psi\land \phi)]$

I think that by completeness theorem this is equivalent to the following:

Let $\Sigma$ be a satisfiable set of propositions and $\phi, \psi$ formulas. Show that

3. If $\Sigma\not\models \phi$ then $\Sigma\models\neg \phi$
4. If $\Sigma\not\models \phi$ then $\Sigma\not\models[\phi\lor (\psi\land \phi)]$.

My attempt: The latter is easy to prove,

3. If $\Sigma\not\models \phi$, then there exists a model $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models \Sigma$ but $\mathcal{A}\not\models \phi$, then $\mathcal{A}\models \neg \phi$, then $\Sigma\models \neg \phi.$
4. If $\Sigma \not\models\phi$ then there exists a models $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\models\Sigma$ but $\mathcal{A}\not\models \phi$ then $\mathcal{A\not\models \phi\land\psi}$, then $\mathcal{A}\not\models \phi\lor (\phi\land\psi)$ and then $\Sigma\not\models [\phi\lor (\psi\land \phi)]$

I appreciate if you tell me if I have any errors, or if I'm right, any help is welcome.

Comment: Your proof of 1 is wrong, but that’s good because it is not true. (Your translation, as well as proof of 2, look fine.)

Comment: Could you tell me where is my error in 1, please? I think that is when I say then if the model $\mathcal{A}\not\models \phi$ then $\mathcal{A}\models \neg \phi$, but I don't know other way for prove this. And I can't think of a counterexample

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ a consistent and _complete_ set of propositions? Otherwise Point 1. does not hold.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Only consistent, you know some counterexample?

Comment: Moreover, are you in propositional logic or in first-order logic?

Comment: First-order logic

Comment: In [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Semantics), the truth value of formulas is given not only by a model (aka interpretation) but also by variable assignment that associates an element of the domain of discourse with each variable (since you are talking about possibly open formulas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that, thanks to [completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (and [soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)) theorem,  proving Points 1 and 2 is equivalent to prove Points 3 and 4.
And your proof of Point 4 is correct.
But your proof of Point 3 is not correct, and actually Point 3 (and hence Point 1) does not hold!

Where is the error in your attempt to prove Point 3? From the fact that $\mathcal{A} \models \lnot \phi$ it does not follow that $\Sigma \models \lnot \phi$.
Indeed, $\Sigma \models \lnot \phi$ means that for *every* model $\mathcal{A}'$, if $\mathcal{A}' \models \Sigma$ then $\mathcal{A}' \models \lnot \phi$.
But in your attempt to prove Point 3, you have just shown that *there exists* a model $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A} \models \Sigma$ and $\mathcal{A} \models \lnot \phi$.
*A priori*, it is still possible that there is another model $\mathcal{B}\models \Sigma$ such that $\mathcal{B} \models \phi$, your argument does not exclude this possibility. And actually this is what actually happens!

Why Point 3 does not hold? Suppose that $\Sigma$ is the set of axioms defining a group (it can be easily expressed in first-order logic, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories#Groups)), and that $\phi$ is the formula expressing that the group is abelian. Clearly, $\Sigma \not\models \phi$ because not all groups are abelian, but from that it does not follow that $\Sigma \models \lnot \phi$ because it is not true that *all* groups are non-abelian.

Comment: Thank you very much!